# Android 4.3 ADB push/pull

Tags: android, adb

Today i bought the Samsung Galaxy Note 3 which came with Android 4.3. Since it's so new, i couldn't find a way to root my device, so instead i tried with the adb connection ... i failed.

So, i used this

```
D:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdk\platform-tools>adb push g:\save15.dat /data/data/com.creativemobile/dragracing/files/
```

but i got this

```
failed to copy 'g:\save15.dat' to '/data/data/com.creativemobile/dragracing/files/': No such file or directory
```

so, is there a way to copy my file to my device?

Answer (score 2):

It should be

> adb push g:\save15.dat /data/data/com.creativemobile.dragracing/files/

If you're allowed to push files/data there it will work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the 
adb restore command for android 4.x.x
but you need to have an adb backup before.
but i think adb shell backup command does not work for android 2.x.x

maybe this will work for you
http://dragracingforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=262&t=13477
if not then you can ask the the post author i think he knows how to.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in 4.3 that prevents this from working on a real, non-rooted device. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the following works on my limited edition nuclearsx-sp5
type these commands

```
adb reboot
adb remount
adb root
```

This is tested to work only on "improperly" (YES! I mean it) rooted devices which are known to have production builds. But it works on my samsung galaxy wonder (non-rooted)flawlessly.

Good luck!